# Python/MySQL Connector: Some queries hang based on the input

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

So I am using the Python MySQL connector, and I am trying to write some code that will select some rows depending on whether or not the row fits the criteria that I give it. This table has a column for chemicals and a column for counties in California (among others)

All of the following lines of code run perfectly through the MySQL console:

```
SELECT wellName, approximateLatitude, approximateLongitude, chemical, result, units, date, county FROM chemicaldata WHERE (county='YOLO') AND (chemical='CR6')

SELECT wellName, approximateLatitude, approximateLongitude, chemical, result, units, date, county FROM chemicaldata WHERE (chemical='CR6')

SELECT wellName, approximateLatitude, approximateLongitude, chemical, result, units, date, county FROM chemicaldata WHERE (chemical='CR')

SELECT wellName, approximateLatitude, approximateLongitude, chemical, result, units, date, county FROM chemicaldata WHERE (county='YOLO') AND (chemical='CR')

SELECT wellName, approximateLatitude, approximateLongitude, chemical, result, units, date, county FROM chemicaldata WHERE (county='YOLO') AND (chemical='NO3')
```

For each statement above, I put the statement in quotes and executed it through python. Then I tried to run a simple script. For example

```
query = "SELECT wellName, approximateLatitude, approximateLongitude, chemical, result, units, date, county FROM chemicaldata WHERE (county='YOLO') AND (chemical='CR')"
cursor.execute(query)
i = 0
for (wellName,approximateLatitude,approximateLongitude,chemical,result,units,date,county) in cursor:
     print i
     i = i+1
```

Can you guys guess which of the above 5 statements the Python script worked on? Only the third and fifth...It makes no sense to me because they are pretty much the same thing accept I changed the chemical, and they all work perfectly on the MySQL command line. To be more specific, when I say the command doesn't work on Python, the counter I have in the loop just freezes in the middle and stops doing anything. For the third and fifth statements, the loop eventually exits and starts printing things out after the loop. Can anyone help me determine what might possibly be wrong or different ways for me to debug my code? I appreciate the help!

Comment: You might need to add something like `results = cursor.fetchall()` after the line `cursor.execute(query)`.

Comment: Unfortunately, same thing happens. Freezes up on the same statements.

Comment: _And_ change your loop to loop through `results`, not `cursor` in case you didn't.

Comment: @figs Also tried that. Problem is that the program freezes before it can get to the loop. It freezes when I do the fetchall.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use slash in query.

```
query = "SELECT wellName, approximateLatitude, approximateLongitude, chemical, result, units, date, county FROM chemicaldata WHERE (county=\'YOLO\') AND (chemical=\'CR\')"
cursor.execute(query)
i = 0
for (wellName,approximateLatitude,approximateLongitude,chemical,result,units,date,county) in cursor:
     print i
     i = i+1
```

Tell me if it works.

Comment: That did not work either. It stops at the exact same values too =(

Comment: @Sidd Did it print anything in the for loop for first query? Which loop did it stop?

Comment: it stops at 423 (it prints 0,1,2,3,4,5.....), while running the command in the console yields 1439 results.

Comment: @Sidd It seems there is something wrong with this record (423). That's why it freezes when you do the fetchall. Check this out.

Comment: I inspected the row at this index and it seems to be okay. Also, using this same logic, the fourth query failed so the third query should have also failed, but it seemed to work fine for the third query. By the way, I really appreciate the help!